# What is this plus sign in a text box in draw.io app, and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: draw.io

I just got a draw.io file (from https://app.diagrams.net/ or the app, draw.io-13.6.2-windows-installer.exe which can be downloaded from the same page), which I try to edit in the app, and I've noticed this in a text box:

[image]

What is that `+` in the box on the left? I cannot delete it as a character; if I click it, it toggles to `-` (so apparently it is meant to expand something - but it is pointless here, there is just one word in the box).

So what is this `+` for - and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out - if you select that text box, right-click it and choose Edit Style, you get this box:

[image]

All you have to do is delete the `container=1;` part, click Apply - and the `+` sign will disappear.